# Error:not implement interface member 'System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, icomparer

I have a class with .IComparable interface,but got error when complied.

Please help take a look and give me a solution.

---

Error   1   'phyl.DnaSequenceTree.Node' does not implement interface member 'System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)'

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


/**
* Class DnaSequenceTree encapsulates a rooted bifurcating tree of DNA
* sequences. Each node in the tree is designated by an index from 0 to
* <I>N</I>&minus;1, where <I>N</I> is the tree's <I>length.</I> The tree's
* <I>capacity</I> <I>C</I> is the maximum number of nodes (specified when the
* tree was constructed). For a tree to hold <I>M</I> tip nodes, the tree's
* capacity must be <I>C</I> &ge; 2<I>M</I>&nbsp;&minus;&nbsp;1.
*
* @author Clark Wang
* @version 09-Feb-2015
*/


namespace phyl
{
    public class DnaSequenceTree
    {
        // Amount of extra padding in arrays.
        private static int PAD = 32;
        // Hidden helper classes.
        // Information about one node in the tree.
        private class Node : IComparable
        {
            // Parent node index, or -1 for the root node.
            public int parent;
            // First child node index, or -1 for a tip node.
            public int child1;
            // Second child node index, or -1 for a tip node.
            public int child2;
            // DNA sequence associated with this node, or null if none.
            public DnaSequence seq;
            // Branch length between this node and its parent, or null if none.
            public Double brlen;

            // Extra padding to avert cache interference.
            private long p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7;
            private long p8, p9, pa, pb, pc, pd, pe, pf;

            // Construct a new, empty node.
            public Node()
            {
                clear();
            }
            // Clear this node.
            public void clear()
            {
                this.parent = -1;
                this.child1 = -1;
                this.child2 = -1;
                this.seq = null;
                this.brlen = 1;
            }
            // Set this node to be a copy of the given node.
            public void copy (Node node)
            {
                this.parent = node.parent;
                this.child1 = node.child1;
                this.child2 = node.child2;
                this.seq = node.seq;
                this.brlen = node.brlen;
            }
            // Compare this node with the given node. The ordering is descending
            // order of branch length. A node with no branch length uses a default
            // branch length of 0.
            public int compareTo(Node node)
            {
                double brlen1 = this.brlen == null ? 0.0 : this.brlen;
                double brlen2 = node.brlen == null ? 0.0 : node.brlen;
                if (brlen1 > brlen2) return -1;
                else if (brlen1 < brlen2) return +1;
                else return 0;
            }
        }
        // Array of nodes.
        Node[] myNode;
        // Tree capacity (maximum number of nodes).
        private int myCapacity;
        // Tree length (actual number of nodes).
        private int myLength;
        // Index of root node, or -1 if tree is empty.
        private int myRoot;
        // Extra padding to avert cache interference.
        private long p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7;
        private long p8, p9, pa, pb, pc, pd, pe, pf;

        public DnaSequenceTree (int C)
        {
            if (C < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException
                ("DnaSequenceTree(): C (= " + C + ") < 0, illegal");
            }
            int temp = C + PAD;
            myNode = new Node[temp];
            for (int i = 0; i < C; ++i)
            {
                myNode[i] = new Node();
            }
            myCapacity = C;
            myLength = 0;
            myRoot = -1;
        }
        // Exported operations.

        /**
         * Returns the capacity of this tree.
         *
         * @return  Capacity <I>C</I> (maximum number of nodes).
         */
        public int capacity()
        {
            return myCapacity;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the length of this tree.
         *
         * @return  Length <I>N</I> (number of nodes).
         */
        public int length()
        {
            return myLength;
        }
        /**
         * Returns the root of this tree.
         *
         * @return  Index of the root node, or &minus;1 if this tree is empty.
         */
        public int root()
        {
            return myRoot;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the parent of the given node in this tree.
         *
         * @param  i  Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
         *
         * @return  Index of the parent of node <TT>i</TT>, or &minus;1 if node
         *          <TT>i</TT> is the root node.
         *
         * @exception  IndexOutOfBoundsException
         *     (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
         */
        public int parent
            (int i)
        {
            if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("DnaSequenceTree.parent(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
            }
            return myNode[i].parent;
        }

        /**
        * Returns the first child of the given node in this tree.
        *
        * @param i Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
        *
        * @return Index of the first child of node <TT>i</TT>, or &minus;1 if node
        * <TT>i</TT> is a tip node.
        *
        * @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
        */
        public int child1 (int i)
        {
            if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("DnaSequenceTree.child1(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
            }
            return myNode[i].child1;
        }

        /**
        * Returns the second child of the given node in this tree.
        *
        * @param i Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
        *
        * @return Index of the second child of node <TT>i</TT>, or &minus;1 if
        * node <TT>i</TT> is a tip node.
        *
        * @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
        */
        public int child2 (int i)
        {
            if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.child2(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
            }
            return myNode[i].child2;
        }


        /**
        * Returns the DNA sequence associated with the given node in this tree.
        *
        * @param i Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
        *
        * @return DNA sequence associated with node <TT>i</TT>, or null if no DNA
        * sequence is associated.
        *
        * @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
        */
        public DnaSequence seq (int i)
        {
            if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.seq(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
            }
            return myNode[i].seq;
        }

        /**
        * Set the DNA sequence associated with the given node in this tree.
        * <P>
        * <I>Note:</I> The tree contains a reference to (not a copy of)
        * <TT>seq</TT>.
        *
        * @param i Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
        * @param seq DNA sequence associated with node <TT>i</TT>, or null if no
        * DNA sequence is associated.
        *
        * @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
        */
        public void seq (int i,DnaSequence seq)
        {
            if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.seq(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
            }
            myNode[i].seq = seq;
        }

        /**
        * Returns the branch length associated with the given node in this tree.
        *
        * @param i Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
        *
        * @return Branch length between node <TT>i</TT> and its parent, or null if
        * no branch length is associated.
        *
        * @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
        */
        public Double branchLength (int i)
        {
            if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.branchLength(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
            }
            return myNode[i].brlen;
        }

        /**
        * Set the branch length associated with the given node in this tree.
        *
        * @param i Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
        * @param brlen Branch length between node <TT>i</TT> and its parent, or
        * null if no branch length is associated.
        *
        * @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
        */
        public void branchLength (int i,Double brlen)
        {
            if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("DnaSequenceTree.branchLength(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
            }
            myNode[i].brlen = brlen;
        }

        /**
        * Clear this DNA sequence tree.
        */
        public void clear()
        {
            int C = myCapacity;
            for (int i = 0; i < C; ++i)
            {
                myNode[i].clear();
            }
            myLength = 0;
            myRoot = -1;
        }

        /**
        * Set this DNA sequence tree to be a copy of the given tree. This tree's
        * capacity is unchanged and must be greater than or equal to the given
        * tree's length. This tree's length, DNA sequences, and branch lengths
        * become the same as <TT>tree</TT>.
        * <P>
        * <I>Note:</I> This tree contains references to (not copies of) the DNA
        * sequences in <TT>tree</TT>.
        *
        * @param tree DNA sequence tree.
        *
        * @exception NullPointerException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>tree</TT> is null.
        * @exception IllegalArgumentException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if this tree's capacity is less than
        * <TT>tree</TT>'s length.
        */
        public void copy (DnaSequenceTree tree)
        {
            // Verify preconditions.
            if (this.myCapacity < tree.myLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.copy(): Capacity (= " + this.myCapacity + ") too small");
            }
            int C = this.myCapacity;
            int N = tree.myLength;
            // Copy <tree>'s nodes to this tree.
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                this.myNode[i].copy(tree.myNode[i]);
            }
            // Clear any unused nodes in this tree.
            for (int i = N; i < C; ++i)
            {
                this.myNode[i].clear();
            }
            // Update this tree's length and root.
            this.myLength = N;
            this.myRoot = tree.myRoot;
        }


        /**
        * Set this DNA sequence tree to be the join of the two given trees. This
        * tree's capacity is unchanged and must be greater than or equal to
        * <I>N</I><SUB>1</SUB>&nbsp;+&nbsp;<I>N</I><SUB>2</SUB>&nbsp;+&nbsp;1,
        * <I>Note:</I> This method may alter the index of this tree's root node.
        *
        * @param tree1 First DNA sequence tree.
        * @param tree2 Second DNA sequence tree.
        *
        * @exception NullPointerException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>tree1</TT> is null. Thrown if
        * <TT>tree2</TT> is null.
        * @exception IllegalArgumentException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if this tree's capacity is less than
        * <I>N</I><SUB>1</SUB>&nbsp;+&nbsp;<I>N</I><SUB>2</SUB>&nbsp;+&nbsp;1.
        */

            public void join (DnaSequenceTree tree1,DnaSequenceTree tree2)
            {
                // Verify preconditions.
                int N1 = tree1.myLength;
                int N2 = tree2.myLength;
                if (this.myCapacity < N1+N2+1)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.join(): Capacity (= "+this.myCapacity+") too small");
                }
                int C = this.myCapacity;
                // Set up this tree's root node at index 0.
                Node root = this.myNode[0];
                root.parent = -1;
                root.child1 = tree1.myRoot + 1;
                root.child2 = tree2.myRoot + N1 + 1;
                root.seq = null;
                root.brlen = 1;

                // Copy <tree1>'s nodes to this tree. Must offset <tree1>'s node
                // indexes by 1.
                for (int i = 0; i < N1; ++ i)
                {
                    Node thisnode = this.myNode[i+1];
                    Node treenode = tree1.myNode[i];
                    thisnode.parent =
                    treenode.parent == -1 ? 0 : treenode.parent + 1;
                    thisnode.child1 =
                    treenode.child1 == -1 ? -1 : treenode.child1 + 1;
                    thisnode.child2 =
                    treenode.child2 == -1 ? -1 : treenode.child2 + 1;
                    thisnode.seq = treenode.seq;
                    thisnode.brlen = treenode.brlen;
                }
                // Copy <tree2>'s nodes to this tree. Must offset <tree2>'s node
                // indexes by N1 + 1.
                for (int i = 0; i < N2; ++ i)
                {
                    Node thisnode = this.myNode[i+N1+1];
                    Node treenode = tree2.myNode[i];
                    thisnode.parent =
                    treenode.parent == -1 ? 0 : treenode.parent + N1 + 1;
                    thisnode.child1 =
                    treenode.child1 == -1 ? -1 : treenode.child1 + N1 + 1;
                    thisnode.child2 =
                    treenode.child2 == -1 ? -1 : treenode.child2 + N1 + 1;
                    thisnode.seq = treenode.seq;
                    thisnode.brlen = treenode.brlen;
                }
                // Clear any unused nodes in this tree.
                for (int i = N1 + N2 + 1; i < C; ++i)
                {
                    this.myNode[i].clear();
                }
                // Update this tree's length and root.
                this.myLength = N1 + N2 + 1;
                this.myRoot = 0;
            }


        /*
        *   * <I>Note:</I> This tree contains a reference to (not a copy of)
        * <TT>seq</TT>.
        * <P>
        * <I>Note:</I> This method may alter the index of this tree's root node.
        *
        * @param i Node index, 0 &le; <TT>i</TT> &le; <I>N</I>&minus;1.
        * @param seq DNA sequence associated with new tip node, or null if no DNA
        * sequence is associated.
        *
        * @return Index of new tip node.
        *
        * @exception IllegalArgumentException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if this tree's capacity is less than
        * this tree's length + 2.
        * @exception IndexOutOfBoundsException
        * (unchecked exception) Thrown if <TT>i</TT> is out of bounds.
        */
            public int add(int i,DnaSequence seq)
            {
                // Case 1: This tree is empty.
                if (myLength == 0)
                {
                // Verify preconditions.
                if (myCapacity < 1)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.add(): Capacity (= "+myCapacity+ ") < 1, illegal");
                }
                    // Set up root node with <seq>.
                    Node root = this.myNode[0];
                    root.parent = -1;
                    root.child1 = -1;
                    root.child2 = -1;
                    root.seq = seq;
                    root.brlen = 1;
                    // Update this tree's length and root.
                    myLength = 1;
                    myRoot = 0;
                    return 0;
                }  else
                {
                    // Verify preconditions.
                    if (myCapacity < myLength + 2)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.add(): Capacity (= " + myCapacity + ") too small");
                    }
                    if (0 > i || i >= myLength)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException ("DnaSequenceTree.add(): Index (= " + i + ") out of bounds");
                    }
                    // Set up new interior node.
                    int parent_i = myNode[i].parent;
                    Node newnode = myNode[myLength];
                    newnode.parent = parent_i;
                    newnode.child1 = i;
                    newnode.child2 = myLength + 1;
                    newnode.seq = null;
                    newnode.brlen = 1;
                    // Splice new interior node between node <i> and node <i>'s parent.
                    // Update this tree's root if necessary.
                    if (parent_i == -1)
                    {
                        myRoot = myLength;
                    }
                    else if (myNode[parent_i].child1 == i)
                    {
                        myNode[parent_i].child1 = myLength;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myNode[parent_i].child2 = myLength;
                    }
                    myNode[i].parent = myLength;
                    // Set up new tip node with <seq>.
                    Node newtip = myNode[myLength + 1];
                    newtip.parent = myLength;
                    newtip.child1 = -1;
                    newtip.child2 = -1;
                    newtip.seq = seq;
                    newtip.brlen = 1;
                    // Update this tree's length.
                    myLength += 2;
                    return myLength - 1;
                }
            }
                public DnaSequenceList toList()
                {
                    // Make a list of just the tip nodes.
                    List<Node> nodelist = new List<Node>();
                    int N = myLength;
                    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++ i)
                    {
                        Node node = myNode[i];
                        if (node.child1 == -1) nodelist.Add (node);
                    }
                // Sort the node list.
                //Collections.sort (nodelist);
                var sortedList = nodelist.OrderBy(a => a.brlen);
                sortedList.ToList(); //这个时候会排序


                int M = nodelist.Capacity;
                // Set up DNA sequence list.
                DnaSequenceList seqlist = new DnaSequenceList();
                seqlist.mySequence = new DnaSequence [M];
                int j = 0;
                foreach (Node node in nodelist)
                {
                    seqlist.mySequence[j++] = node.seq;
                }
                return seqlist;
                }

            public String toString()
                {
                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                    if (myLength == 0)
                    {
                        buf.Append('(');
                        buf.Append(')');
                    }
                    else if (myLength == 1)
                    {
                        buf.Append('(');
                        toString(buf, 0);
                        buf.Append(')');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toString(buf, myRoot);
                    }
                    buf.Append(';');
                    return toString();
                }

            private void toString (StringBuilder buf,int index)
            {
                Node node = myNode[index];
                if (node.child1 != -1)
                {
                    buf.Append('(');
                    toString(buf, node.child1);
                    buf.Append(',');
                    toString(buf, node.child2);
                    buf.Append(')');
                }
                buf.Append(nodeName(node));
                if (node.brlen != null)
                {
                    buf.Append(':');
                    buf.Append(node.brlen);
                }
            }

            private String nodeName(Node node)
            {
                return node.seq == null || node.seq.myName == null ? "" : node.seq.myName.Replace("\\s+", "_");
            }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the method's signature carefully. The signature of `IComparable.CompareTo` is `int CompareTo(object)`. Your method:

1. Has the wrong casing. Compare your `compareTo` with `CompareTo` (C# is case-sensitive).
2. Has the wrong type for its first argument. Compare your `compareTo(Node)` with `CompareTo(object)`.

You will need to a)fix your casing, and b)implement `CompareTo(object)`. For example:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    var node = obj as Node;
    if(node == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot compare objects of different type");

    return CompareTo(node);
}
```